# How do you properly split up casperjs tests with a shared browser instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs

I'm trying to test different parts of a "mostly" single page application.  I'd like to split the tests up, but I really only want to load the page once and then have the tests go through and click the links etc.

Here's my code:

PRE.js

```
var port = require('system').env.PORT
var tester;

casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 768};

casper.test.begin('Test login', function suite(test) {
    var done = false;
    casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
        this.echo("Error:    " + msg, "ERROR");
        this.echo("file:     " + trace[0].file, "WARNING");
        this.echo("line:     " + trace[0].line, "WARNING");
        this.echo("function: " + trace[0]["function"], "WARNING");
    });

    casper.on('remote.message', function(message) {
        this.echo('remote message caught: ' + message);
        if (message == "done") { 
            done = true;
        }
    });

    casper.start('http://localhost:' + port, function() {

    // Verify that the main menu links are present.
        test.assertExists('input[name=username]');
        // 10 articles should be listed.
        test.assertElementCount('input', 3);
        casper.fill("form", {
            "username": "username",
            "password": "my password goes right here you cant have it"
        }, true);
        casper.then(function() {
                casper.waitFor(function(){
                    return done;
                    }, function(){
                    tester = casper.evaluate(function(){
                        return tester;
                    });
                    test.assert("undefined" != typeof tester);
                    test.assert(Object.keys(tester).length > 0);
                });
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

and then I have a second file (and there will be lots more like this):
TEST.js

```
casper.test.assert(true);

casper.capture('.screenshot.png');
casper.test.done();
```

I'm hoping to get a screenshot of the browser session from pre.js.

I run it from a specialized program that starts up my program, but in essence it runs:

```
casperjs test casper_tests --pre=pre.js
```

casper_tests holds both files above

My Question:

What's the right way to do this?  No screenshot is being taken, and perhaps more important (though I haven't tried it yet) I want to be able to click things inside and verify that other pieces are working.  The screenshot just verifies that i'm in the right neighborhood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not be easily possible and potentially dangerous. Every action that you do, would need to be reversed to not break the other tests. If you later decide that writing tests in a modular manner is a good thing, you will have a headache writing your tests.

PRE.js will be your start script which you modify to execute your tests in between. In the following fully working example you see how you can schedule multiple test cases for one execution of casper. This is bad, because the `canvas` test case depends on the proper `back` execution of the `link` test case.

```
casper.start('http://example.com');
casper.then(function() {
    this.test.begin("link", function(test){
        var url = casper.getCurrentUrl();
        test.assertExists("a");
        casper.click("a");
        casper.then(function(){
            test.assert(this.getCurrentUrl() !== url);
            this.back(); // this is bad
            test.done();
        });
    });
    this.test.begin("canvas", function(test){
        test.assertNotExists("canvas");
        test.done();
    });
});
casper.run();
```

Of course you can open the root again for the new test case, but then you have the same problem as with your initial code.

```
var url = 'http://example.com';
casper.start();
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.test.begin("link", function(test){
        var url = casper.getCurrentUrl();
        test.assertExists("a");
        casper.click("a");
        casper.then(function(){
            test.assert(this.getCurrentUrl() !== url);
            test.done();
        });
    });
});
casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    this.test.begin("canvas", function(test){
        test.assertNotExists("canvas");
        test.done();
    });
});
casper.run();
```

Now the test cases don't depend on each other, but you also load the page multiple times.

---

If you need some initial actions for every test case then the PRE.js is not the right place for that.

Create include.js and put the following code there:

```
function login(suite, username, password){
    username = username || "defaultUsername";
    password = password || "defaultPassword";
    casper.test.begin('Test login', function suite(test) {
        var done = false;
        // event handlers

        casper.start('http://localhost:' + port, function() {
            // login if the session expired or it is the first run
            if (!loggedIn) {
                // login
            }
            // wait
        });

        casper.then(function(){
            suite.call(casper, test);
        });

        casper.run(function() {
            test.done();
        });
    });
}
```

Then you can run it as `casperjs test casper_tests --includes=include.js` with test files like

```
login(function(test){
    this.click("#something");
    this.waitForSelector(".somethingChanged");
    this.then(function(){
        test.assertExists(".somethingElseAlsoHappened");
    });
});
```

Of course you can have different `login` functions (with different names) or more lightweight ones.

---

Building on the previous snippets, you can make a start script and load the test files yourself. Then you have all the flexibility you need to do this.

include.js:

```
function login(testScript, username, password, next){
    // event handlers

    casper.start('http://localhost:' + port, function() {
        // login if the session expired or it is the first run
        // waiting
    });

    testScript.forEach(function(case){
        casper.thenOpen(case.name, function(){
            this.test.begin(function suite(test){
                case.func.call(casper, test);
                casper.then(function(){
                    test.done();
                });
            });
        });
    });

    casper.run(next);
}
```

start.js:

```
// pass the test file folder to the script and read it with sys.args
// fs.list(path) all files in that path and iterate over them
var filesContents = files.map(function(filename){
    return require(filename).testcases;
});
var end = null;
// stack the test cases into the `run` callback of the previous execution
filesContents.forEach(function(case){
    var newEnd = end;
    var newFunc = function(){ login(case, u, p, newEnd) };
    end = newFunc;
});
end(); // run the stack in reverse
```

each test file would look like this:

```
exports.testcases = [
    {
        name: "sometest",
        func: function(test){
            test.assert(true)
            this.echo(this.getCurrenturl());
        }
    },
    {
        name: "sometest2",
        func: function(test){
            test.assert(true)
            this.echo(this.getCurrenturl());
        }
    },
];
```

This is just a suggestion.

Comment: What if we assume that test cases don't have to be reversed? (which I definitely understand is against normal testing philosophy).  I will play with the include idea though, but that still doesn't share a browser session.

Comment: Yes, it does. It will be the same session if you don't remove cookies. Every test case and test file is run on the same phantomjs instance and cookies are never removed from casper itself.

Comment: sorry, I mean in the same browser page instance.  It will still have to reload the page between each test, which I'm trying to find a way to avoid (there are different suites, and I'd like each suite to run in a single browser load)

Comment: (btw, i don't argue that the answer above is the proper way, and I will definitely be taking the advice, there's just the other half that I want to figure out how to do)